# Conflicting boundary information

Tags: administrative-boundaries, borders, germany, austria

When I query, for example, the Germany Boundary Commission, and the Austrian Boundary Commission, for boundary information, I am getting conflicting data sets. Is there a resolution method for this?

Comment: I suppose you mean that the two polygons do not have exactly same vertices. That is very common problem when using data from different sources together. Even it is possible to fix the topology, who knows which dataset has better vertices. Perhaps the advanced example of this answer can help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143695/create-common-vertexes-between-shared-polygon-boundaries-in-postgis/143719#143719

Comment: @user30184; i had assumed that the borders (vertex set) would match up, but no matter what i try i can't get this to be the case

Comment: If you receive adjacent polygons from two companies or agencies it is best to assume that the vertices do not match. Opposite situation would be a happy surprise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a particular reason for using the boundary commissions, you can get national boundaries from the [downloads at Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) (this includes contested areas - if there are any in your area of interest). Go to the link, look under "Large Scale" and then "Cultural" for the files you will need.

Comment: or for larger scales look at the EU http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units